# How to specify a content character set in web request on c#?

Tags: c#, character-encoding, httpwebrequest

here is a code of a function that makes a request to remote web-site:

```
private static string translatePage(string text, string langPair, Encoding encoding) {
    string urlBabelfish = "http://babelfish.yahoo.com/translate_txt";
    string urlReverso = "http://www.reverso.net/text_translation.aspx?lang=RU#";
    string url = "";

    // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(urlBabelfish);

    // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
    request.Method = "POST";

    // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
    string postData = string.Format("lp={0}&trtext={1}", langPair, text);
    byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

    // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(
        request.ContentType);
    ct.CharSet = encoding.ToString();
    request.ContentType = ct.ToString();

    // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

    // Get the request stream.
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

    // Write the data to the request stream.
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

    // Close the Stream object.
    dataStream.Close();

    // Get the response.
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    // Display the status.
    Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

    // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
    string resPage = "";
    using (dataStream)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dataStream, encoding))
            resPage = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
    response.Close();

    return resPage;
}
```

Calling this function with input parameter `langPair="en_ru"` returns a page with wrong encoding that doesn't  allow cyrilic symbols. The ContentType meta-tag looks like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

And all cyrilic symbols become `'\0'`.

If I perform the request manually in browser with the same parameters, it returns fine page of `UTF-8` encoding with tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">.
```

I want my code to do the same. I pass `UTF-8` as the Encoding parameter, but it does not affect the ContentType metatag.

What can I do in my code to make the request return a page of the encoding I need?

Answer (score 1):

Check `response.ContentType`. It should include a `charset=` parameter. You can use that to create the proper `Encoding` to use when creating your `StreamReader`.

Comment: The default encoding is not proper for me. I need to get a response in UTF-8, like it's returned in browser when executed manually. But response.ContentType is read-only.

Comment: As I can guess, the response is encoded unproperly by itself and setting the StreamReader encoding will not affect the result. I need a way to get response encoded correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Jim Mischel's answer helped me.

If you want to know how to set a ContentType and CharSet, this is how to do it:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://yourwebsite.com:80/Api/")
{
    Content = new StringContent(messageBodyAsString)
};
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")
{
    CharSet = "utf-8"
};
```

The request will then send `Content-Type` with the value `application/json; charset=utf-8`